# Firebase in jax-rs or servlet

Tags: rest, servlets, firebase

How can I use the Firebase java client from within a jax-rs service?
Let's say I make a the following call? That's an async callback?

```
authClient.checkAuthStatus(new SimpleLoginAuthenticatedHandler() {
    @Override
    public void authenticated(FirebaseSimpleLoginError error, FirebaseSimpleLoginUser user) {
        if (error != null) {
            result = "{\"result\" : \"Error checking authentication\"}";
        } else if (user == null) {
            result = "{\"result\" : \"Not logged in\"}";
        } else {
            deferred.resolve("done");
        }
    }
});
```

The jax-rs resource is returned before the completion of that async method. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: "make it work"? Are you looking for a way to make the asynchronous code synchronous? (and can we assume you've looked at how this example works? https://github.com/firebase/simple-login-demo-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/samples/simplelogindemo/MainActivity.java#L154)

Comment: Thanks for the link, yes I know how it works. Right, I guess it boils down to making the asynchronous code synchronous. Looks like there are some patterns for that. Else I guess this would be a good candidate for Jax-rs AsynchResponse.